# Standard shortcuts suddenly don't work in applications

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

In some applications (like gedit or MS Word) the standard <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> / <kbd>c</kbd> / <kbd>z</kbd> / <kbd>y</kbd> / <kbd>s</kbd> shotcuts have stopped working.

Instead I have to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ins</kbd> for copying, <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>ins</kbd> for pasting and so on.

This, as you can guess, is really annoying (though in gedit it strongly discourages cut and paste code if you know if I mean). But still, what have I done wrong and how I can fix it? In the system as a whole, standard shortcuts are working OK, and only some applications are affected.

Comment: Have you recently install any new application? This comes through my mind first because I believe it catches all the events from keyboard and doesn't forward them to others as usual.

Comment: Actually now, but I'm working on the laptop provided to me by my employing company. But the first three months I was working on it there was no problem.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Word, check Options under Customize Ribbon to make sure your shortcuts have not been altered. If so, you may need to reset.